# How to set the maximum horizontal axis range in a line chart in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, linechart, ssrs-2016

I have a line chart with markers in ssrs that is currently displaying 4 months of data (Jan through Apr).  I would like the maximum horizontal chart range to extend from Jan to Dec.  It's automatically filling the chart window up to Apr because I only have data up to the point so far.  How do I force the horizontal axis range to go from Jan to Dec?  Would a min and max axis range expression do this? I'm having trouble finding an example.  This is what I currently have. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your report does not need to show spanning across years then..

Right-click on the horizontal axis and setup as follows...

[image]